# max id 2 condignated label vba fomulas

Tags: excel, formulas

Hi i need a result with max ID in range,

structure is

- LABEL | ID | cOMM

  - 1.1 |
  - 1.2 |
  - 1.3 | ITS
    etc..

I have a mean result from "C" columns

I can't use VBA

It's result make manual
http://srv3.sendfile.pl/pobierz/951928---gbkg/5316677400_1326980696.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into cell B3 and fill down using mouse:

```
=A3&"."&COUNTIF($A$3:A3,A3)
```

Comment: i have a mean with MAX ID from "C" column, with label "ITS"

1.1
1.2 ITS
2.1 ITS
3.1
3.2
3.3 ITS

Comment: Did you mean id increment according to label "ITS" or just adding label to values in column B? Clearify your aim.